# What is the analogy of displacement vector w.r.t Magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields

Is the Displacement vector of Electrostatics similar to H field or B field of magnetism?

I have gone through different sites, but it's making me confuse.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write $D=\mu_0 E + P$ and $B = \mu_0 H + M$, the analogy is fairly strong. Whether you consider that "similar" is something only you can determine. Certainly, they are mathematically similar.

Comment: So, D and B are analogous to each other? 
Also, is D the electric field produced due to the free charges only or due to both of the free and bound charges ?

Comment: Mathematically, perhaps.  But physically, $B$ and $E$ are the fields produced by *all* charges and currents, while $H$ and $D$ are produced by free charges and currents, the bound charges being accounted for by the polarizability of whatever medium.   That this is so can be seen easily from the defining statements for $E$ and $B$: Coulomb's Law and the Biot-Savart Law.  But as you say, "similar" is up to the beholder.

Comment: So when we write D =  εE  = q, so the "q" over here refers to the free charges of the capacitor plate (if considering capacitor for example)

Comment: Floris, you might consider pointing out the similarity with units; E (H) is volts (amps) per meter and thus an electric (magnetic) *field strength*, D (B) is Coulombs (Webers) per square meter and thus an electric (magnetic) *flux density*.

Comment: Can you please try to explain me all the four B D E and H by their definition and formula relating it? Detailed as well as Brief explanations both will be accepted.

Comment: I just want to get it clear in my mind.

Comment: Okay, So mathematically we can say that B and D are analogous, whereas B and E are physically similar as garyp stated.

Comment: Further from the equation
, Just like H depends on the Free current density,  D depends only upon the density of free charges, it is not altered by the introduction of the dielectric.

In this way D and H are analogous.